# SQL - Select distinct rows and join them with another table to get data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

1) person (person_id, person_name)

2) cars (car_id, person_id)

I want to get all the people's names that have cars with no duplicates.

This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT person.person_name, cars.person_id
FROM cars
INNER JOIN person
ON person.person_id=cars.person_id
```

But I don't want duplicates, so I need to incorporate it using something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM cars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.person_id AS person_id, p.name AS name FROM person p, cars c    
WHERE p.person_id = c.person_id    
GROUP BY b.brand_id
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select person_name from person
where person_id in ( select person_id from cars )
```

Comment: This is a nice simple answer that should work if `name` is changed to `person_name`.

Comment: thanks @Ben... finger memory beats out actual reading of the question :)

Comment: do you mean: `select name from person
where person_id in ( select distinct person_id from cars )`

Comment: that would be equivalent - no need to specify the distinct inside the IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.person_name, person.person_id
FROM cars
INNER JOIN person
ON person.person_id=cars.person_id
```

Although there may be more performant alternatives.

Comment: what if there are duplicate names?

Comment: Technically if it's a different `person_id` then it's a different *person*. Is that the specification? If so, most of these answers don't meet that.

Comment: the _id's are primary keys, but there could be duplicate names.

Comment: I'd argue you have poor data then. Only the answer by **Arthur Frankel** will give you unique names.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(person.person_name) 
FROM person, cars 
WHERE person.person_id = cars.person_id
```

Comment: I need the person id as well. can I do this? `SELECT DISTINCT(person.person_name), person.person_id 
FROM person, cars 
WHERE person.person_id = cars.person_id`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  p.person_id, p.person_name
   FROM  person p
WHERE     EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
      FROM cars c
    WHERE c.person_id = p.person_id
)
```